# How to show menu layout in mainactivity layout in the preview window in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am making a custom menu with icons and I want to know if its possible to see how the menu on the toolbar looks **without** running the program on the emulator nor on a android device.

I'm wondering if this can be done the way you can temporarily preview things by including the `tools` namespace:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

in your layout file. Then you would just put something like either of these:

```
tools:text="text here that is previewed only"
tools:layout="@layout/some_layout"
```

So can I do this with a menu resource file? Because when I make the menu file I want it to show the formatting of my theme. I tried messing around with different `tools` attributes and tried to set it to my menu file but nothing was working. Here's how it looks currently because I can't see the layout with my theme settings:

[image]

If that's not possible, can I see how the menu looks with my theme settings in another layout file?